# Can Anybody Help Me On How To Change Square And Cube From An Option To Two Buttons

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, can somebody just tell me how to turn these into buttons which I can click instead of options, that would be really helpful.

Thank You

```js
function check() {
  //All Variables
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
  var oper = document.getElementById("operator").value;

  //If Statements
  if (oper === "Sqaure") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The square root of " + num + " is " + Math.sqrt(num);
  }
  if (oper === "Cube") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The cube root of " + num + " is " + Math.cbrt(num);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

#btn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" id="n1" /><br>
<select id="operator">
  <option value="Sqaure">Square Root</option>
  <option value="Cube">Cube Root</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Find" onclick="check();" id="btn1" /><br><br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `select` field and add in a second (button) `input` field.

The `onclick` attribute of both buttons can pass the desired operation to the `check` function.

Inside the `check` function, everything remains the same -- except there is no need to retrieve the operator, since its now an argument to the function.

Consider the following live snippet which achieves the above. It also uses [`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if the entered data is a valid number -- and if not, display an error message instead.

```js
function check(operation) {
    const num = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Please enter a number';
    } else {
        let root;
        if (operation === "square") {
            root = Math.sqrt(num);
        } else if (operation === "cube") {
            root = Math.cbrt(num);
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `The ${operation} root of ${num} is ${root}`;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    user-select: none;
}

#btn1 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Number:
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" id="n1">
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Square Root" onclick="check('square');" id="btn1">
    <input type="button" value="Cube Root" onclick="check('cube');" id="btn2">
</p>
<p id="result"></p>
```